# airflow connection_closed_abruptly

Tags: python, rabbitmq, airflow

I have a problem with airflow (  v1.9.0dev0+apache.incubating )
 and anything looks working fine until the scheduler gets the job it crashes with this log:

```
[2017-03-15 15:54:18,075] {jobs.py:1329} INFO - Waiting up to 5s for processes to exit... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('airflow==1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating', 'airflow')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 738, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1499, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 839, in scheduler
    job.run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/airflow/jobs.py", line 200, in run
    self._execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/airflow/jobs.py", line 1309, in _execute
    self._execute_helper(processor_manager)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/airflow/jobs.py", line 1441, in _execute_helper
    self.executor.heartbeat()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/airflow/executors/base_executor.py", line 132, in heartbeat
    self.sync()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.9.0.dev0+apache.incubating-py2.7.egg/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 88, in sync
    state = async.state   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 431, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 370, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 156, in get_task_meta
    binding.declare()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 604, in declare
    self._create_exchange(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 611, in
_create_exchange
    self.exchange.declare(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 185, in declare
    nowait=nowait, passive=passive,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 630, in exchange_declare
    wait=None if nowait else spec.Exchange.DeclareOk,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 64, in send_method
    conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 174, in write_frame
    write(view[:offset])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 269, in write
    self._write(s)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

On rabbitmq log I see:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 15-Mar-2017::15:54:17 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.492.0> (127.0.0.1:42970 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 15-Mar-2017::15:54:18 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.492.0> (127.0.0.1:42970 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

Which looks like the client is doing something weird when closes the connection. 
Before the 1.9.0 I user the 1.7.1.3 which reports the same problem ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-342).

Does somebody fixed this in some way ? 
Any idea about where to put hands ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, connection closing seems was initiated by rabbitmq. You may want to do `tcpdump` to confirm this.

It might be something related to security settings (username/password, or security settings). Did you do

> #### Configure RabbitMQ: create user and grant privileges rabbitmqctl add_user rabbitmq_user_name rabbitmq_password rabbitmqctl add_vhost
>
> rabbitmq_virtual_host_name rabbitmqctl set_user_tags
>   rabbitmq_user_name rabbitmq_tag_name rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p
>   rabbitmq_virtual_host_name rabbitmq_user_name ".*" ".*" ".*"

Taken from https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html

If that's not the case, then it could be that for example rabbitmq is configured to use TLS and airflow/celery is not, or something like that - try using something Ethereal which supports RabbitMQ protocol - see for example https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-wireshark.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The connection is closed by RST from RABBITMQ after the client issues FIN. Something is not following the protocol ( at least so it looks )

Comment: Thanks for sharing your results. I'd recommend posting this question to RabbitMQ and/or Airflow user groups. Given your question has only 15 views, I think you'll get a quicker response there.

Comment: Good idea. It looks like that amqp is not sent the STOMP before the TCP FIN. A lot of people uses AIRFLOW with REDIS instead RABBITMQ, maybe some assumption used into airflow works better with it.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd did you find a conclusive answer on the cause for this? I'm having the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you guys use SSL/TLS setup in RabbitMQ? I've seen in general broken connections boken abruptly like this if ssl/tls negotiation falls apart.

Comment: I was not using SSL, but I switched to redis and all is well. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Bryan: I downgraded to 1.8.x and anything worked fine.